# Why does Sam Quint smash the CB radio?

Tags: plot-explanation, jaws

Why does Sam Quint smash the CB radio in [*Jaws*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073195/)?

When Brody goes and tries to call for help on the CB radio, Sam walks over with a club and smashes it but the movie doesn't really do a good job in explaining his actions. Is it because of Sam's history with sharks on the USS Indianapolis, and he feels like calling for help would be the cheap way out? Does he think that since his friends didn't get to call for help so he shouldn't either?

Comment: I feel it was personal and he wanted vengeance based on his experience on the Indianapolis. There have been analysis that his character is based on Ahab in Moby Dickinson. Here is another's analysis. http://blockbusteranthropology.blogspot.com/2011/01/does-jaws-shark-have-eyes-of-god.html

Comment: Quint has no first name. "Sam" was invented by an internet fanboy several years ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that it is due to one of the following:

1. He wants to focus those on board to the task at hand. If there's no hope of help then the *only* thing they can do is kill the shark.
2. It's basically a macho thing that says *'I don't need anyone's help'*. After all Quint is a loner who basically doesn't ask for help and expects none.

Whichever way, the story would not have been so good if the whole town had turned out to help !

Comment: I actually would consider this happening as a mixture of the two, rather than one or the other. Good answer, Pat.

Comment: Quint is such a great movie character.

Comment: I would add that perhaps more boats would scare off the shark, ruining their chances of killing it.

Answer (score 5):

I think secretly he never really intended to return ashore if he failed, he felt guilty he survived Indianapolis whilst several if not all of his friends perished. For him, being taken by the shark is like an honourable discharge and he's going down to be reunited with his buddies from WW2.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason Quint smashed the radio is because back in the 70's 10,000 dollars was a lot and he didn't want to get help from others so they could get the share and he wanted the money for himself. 
But I do also believe that he smashed it is because he believed it would be dishonourable to receive assistance because of his experience on the USS Indianapolis and he wanted to be brave to impress his friends who weren't there.